# Send int array from java to c with Socket

Tags: java, android, c, arrays, sockets

I want to send `int` array from Android Client to Linux server with socket.

I have int[] angleInt and it has -10,15,20.

My goal is that Linux server can receive -10,15,20.

This is my Android code send part

```
public void SendAngle(float[] angleValue) {

    try {

        angleInt[0] = (int)(angleValue[0]*10);
        angleInt[1] = (int)(angleValue[1]*10);
        angleInt[2] = (int)(angleValue[2]*10);

        Log.d("Angle", angleInt.toString());
        out.println(angleInt);


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

and This is Linux server code receive part

```
while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 20 , 0)) > 0 )
{
    //Send the message back to client
    printf(client_message);
}
```

- char client_message[20]
- int[] angleInt = new int[3]
- PrintWriter out

If I send a `String` from Android to Linux, it works fine.

I'd like to receive that array then save array's value into separate variables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really understand what is your problem and what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Let's see.... Assuming `angleInt` is an `int[]` (you didn't say), the code `println(angleInt)` will write something like `[I@659e0bfd\n` to the Writer. Doubt that's what you want. What *do* you want the socket message to be? Something like `1,2,3` perhaps?

Comment: If you are asking for a way to receive something on the client side you should show the code sending on the server side (or a precise definition of the protocol, i.e., the message contents - char[20] is insufficient.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that's what i want. Server also receive '[I@659e0bfd\n' , but i want to receive '1,2,3'.

Comment: So if you want the 3 numbers separated by commas, why don't you, you know, print the 3 numbers separated by commas? `out.println(angleInt[0] + "," + angleInt[1] + "," + angleInt[2])`

Comment: @Andreas If i do that, client_message has separate value. I mean, if number is -10,20,15, than client_message[0] has '-', client_message[1] has '1', client_message[2] has '0'. I want to save '-10' into int variable.

Comment: What variable? What are you talking about? You are sending a "message", which is a sequence of *bytes*, which seems to be an encoding of characters in your case. So, the "message" is a sequence of characters. There are no "variables" in the message. You have to encode your values into a "text message" on the sending end, and decode the text message back into separate values on the receiving end. So far, you've established that the message should be the text something like `"-10,15,20"` (a 9 character text message). Now build that when sending, and parse that when receiving.

Comment: @Andreas I got it. I'm so thanks your help. I misunderstanded what i sent and you makes me know it. So thanks